# Export two components as library

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have a TypeScript Vue project. Inside of this project I have two components: Cookiebar and CookiebarOpener (CbOpener).
My goal is to export these two components as a library so I can use them at three different websites like:

```html
<p>Some website content</p>
<div id="app">
    <cookiebar></cookiebar>
    <span>Other website content<span>
    <cbopener>
       <span>Open layer</span>
    </cbopener>
</div>
```

I have tried to export the library via 
`"build-cookiebar": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name cookiebar src/components/cookiebar.vue src/components/cbopener.vue "`
but only the cookiebar without the cbopener is exported.

Do you have any guesses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your build command should be:

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name dummylib src/main.js
```

and your src/main.js file should thus look like something like:

```
import cookiebar from './src/components/cookiebar.vue'
import cbopener from './src/components/cbopener.vue'

export default {
  cookiebar,
  cbopener
}
```

I've actually write an entire post about this topic that you can find here: https://medium.com/@olivierpicault/create-a-vue-js-component-library-as-a-module-part-1-a1116e632751

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for post on medium, but I'm getting linter errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60670539/importing-self-made-library-into-vue-project

same issue was pointed here: https://medium.com/@michaelsperber01/thank-you-this-really-helped-me-on-my-way-8f32beeb4816

Could you please tell how to overcome this?

Comment: Hi @KrasnokutskiyEA looks like you got an answer to your question. Sorry for the late answer, I just saw your comment.

Comment: Never mind, @Olivier Picault! 

Though, one more question: Is HMR supposed to work when changes are applied to `DummyButton.vue`? In my case HMR works only when changes are applied to `App.vue` (sampleapp)... 

So, everytime `DummyButton.vue`'s code is changed, I should completely reinstall `dummylib` or `npm unlink dummylib` and then link it again to see changes. And that's not a pleasant development process...

Comment: Yeah @KrasnokutskiyEA I faced this issue as well. Two possibilities:
- You can use yarn link (same feature should exist with npm): https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/
- You can use lerna if both projects are within the same rep: https://github.com/lerna/lerna
Hope this helps