# Importing self-made library into vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, vue-cli

**Intro:** I've generated two projects with vue-cli ~4.2.0: `parent-app` and `dummylib`

**Goal:** to create `DummyButton.vue` component in `dummylib` project and import it in `parent-app` project.

**What I've done:**

Followed this [tutorial](https://itnext.io/create-a-vue-js-component-library-as-a-module-part-1-a1116e632751).

In dummylib's *package.json* I've inserted:

```
"main": "./dist/dummylib.common.js",
```

and build-lib script:

```
"build-lib": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name dummylib src/main.js",
```

dummylib's main.js:

```
import DummyButton from './components/DummyButton.vue'

export default DummyButton
```

Also I've created `DummyButton.vue` and now `vue serve src/components/DummyButton.vue` successfully renders DummyButton component and `npm run build-lib` generates *dist* folder with `dummylib.common.js`

In `parent-app` project I've made `npm i ../dummylib` and it has been added to `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "dummylib": "file:../dummylib",
  ...
},
```

**Problem:**

When I try to start `parent-app` with `npm run serve` a lot of linting errors occurs in `../dummylib/dist/dummylib.common.js`. As far as i understand, ESlint should not even try to process `dummylib.common.js`, but it does and it results in ~2000 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same tutorial a while ago. To fix it: in the main.js of the library I had to do has to do this:

```
const Components = {
  DummyButton
};

Object.keys(Components).forEach(name => {
  Vue.component(name, Components[name]);
});

export default Components;
```

instead of

```
export default DummyButton
```

Also did you remember to import the lib into your parents apps main.js

```
import DummyLib from "DummyLib";
Vue.use(DummyLib);
```

You can also import straight into a component like so:

```
import DummyLib from "DummyLib";
export default {
  components: {
    ...DummyLib
  },
  //... rest of vue file script ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response! 

I forgot to add `Vue.use(dummylib) ` in `parent-app`'s `main.js`.
Though, not sure about your solution in library's `main.js` with `Object.keys().forEach()` ... What profit does it give?  In case when I'm just importing and exporting component everything also works and I'm getting `dummylib.common.js` smaller in size.

Comment: `Object.keys().forEach()` was used as we have a huge list of components to export and this was the easiest method for us